# Radcontrol using MVC master page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I cannot use RadMenu Control in master page with MVC pattern (MVC Framework 3.5)?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately any 3rd Party controls that depend on ViewState (which most do) will not work using the .NET MVC Framework as ViewState only exists in the WebForms paradigm.

I would check the JQuery plugins to see if you can find one which meets your requirments. 
http://plugins.jquery.com/

It should be said that server controls that don't use ViewState will still work however.